# Sum up properties of matching properties in list of objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

In javascript I have an array of objects that looks like this

```
[{symbol: "SYM", value: 1}, {symbol: "SYM", value: 1}, {symbol: "DOG", value: 2}]
```

How do I reduce it to be

```
[{symbol: "SYM", value: 2}, {symbol: "DOG", value: 2}]
```

I.e. sum up the values of matching symbols

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let obj = [{symbol: "SYM", value: 1}, {symbol: "SYM", value: 1}, {symbol: "DOG", value: 2}]

let op = obj.reduce((out,inp)=>{
  if(out[inp.symbol]){
    out[inp.symbol].value+= inp.value
  } else {
    out[inp.symbol] = inp
  }
  return out
},{})


console.log(Object.values(op))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [{symbol: "SYM", value: 1}, {symbol: "SYM", value: 1}, {symbol: "DOG", value: 2}];
valMap = arr.reduce((acc,val) => {
    if(!acc[val.symbol]) acc[val.symbol]=val.value;
    else acc[val.symbol] += val.value;
    return acc;
} ,{});
const result = Object.keys(valMap).map(key => ({symbol:key, value:valMap[key]}));
```

Comment: I haven't used lodash, but if you aren't using the library, it may be an overkill to use it to get this working. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash's `_.groupBy()` and `_.sumBy()`:

```js
const fn = _.flow(
  arr => _.groupBy(arr, 'symbol'),
  groups => _.map(groups, g => 
    _.assign({}, _.head(g), { value: _.sumBy(g, 'value') })
  )
);

const arr = [{symbol: "SYM", value: 1}, {symbol: "SYM", value: 1}, {symbol: "DOG", value: 2}]

const result = fn(arr);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```